# Blank Jframe load on chat TCP

Tags: java, swing, tcp

i try to write a chat TCP. if i run file server and client independently, it is ok. But if i run by use other jframe, which has host button to run server, it will show a blank jframe

```
{
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        FrmServer f=new FrmServer();
        f.setVisible(true);
    } 
}
```

this is FrmServer

```
 public FrmServer() throws HeadlessException {
    setTitle("Server");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    addContent();
    addSend();

    setSize(400, 300);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    chat();
}
private ServerSocket serverInfo;
private Socket clientInfo;
private ObjectInputStream ois;
private ObjectOutputStream oos;

private void chat() {
    try {
        serverInfo = new ServerSocket(12345);

        clientInfo = serverInfo.accept();
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientInfo.getInputStream());

        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientInfo.getOutputStream());

        while (true) {
            String data = ois.readObject().toString();

            txtContent.append("Client :" + data + "\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant code, i.e. the `FrmServer` class?

Comment: I edited question, add FrmServer class

Comment: I think you are working on the Event Dispatch Thread. You should start a new one and call back to EDT through `SwingUtilities`.

Comment: @GáborBakos can you tell me more?,

Comment: @LeThang Added an answer. I hope it will work for you (and I did not make a mistake).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the modified code using a new thread (though not tried):

```
 public FrmServer() throws HeadlessException {
    setTitle("Server");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    addContent();
    addSend();

    setSize(400, 300);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    chat();
}
private ServerSocket serverInfo;
private Socket clientInfo;
private ObjectInputStream ois;
private ObjectOutputStream oos;

private void chat() {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                serverInfo = new ServerSocket(12345);

                clientInfo = serverInfo.accept();
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientInfo.getInputStream());

                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientInfo.getOutputStream());

                while (true) {
                    String data = ois.readObject().toString();
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run(){
                            txtContent.append("Client :" + data + "\n");
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }

        }
    };
    //You can use a ThreadPool too.
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

With Java 8 you can improve the syntax.

The important thing is you should not do anything time consuming on the Swing/AWT Event Dispatch Thread. Connecting to a server, waiting for reply certainly time consuming. Though the catch is, you cannot update the UI from other threads. So you need the `SwingUtilities` class to execute code on EDT.

[Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial might help understanding the details.

Comment: @LeThang, don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.