# Displaying the command prompt?

Tags: java, cmd, processbuilder

I have written this code, using a ProcessBuilder I can run commands via an external command prompt used by the OS. I can get the returned data and use it. But my problem is that I want to display the cmd to the user because the returned data is only returned when the cmd exits. I want it to be returned dynamically, so the user can watch what is returned during the execution of the program.

This starts the cmd and runs the commands, but it doesn't display the actual cmd...

I want to display it or have the data returned at the same pace as it does within the cmd. Please any help?

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd " + directoryPath + " && java " + filePathWithoutExtension);

    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = builder.start();

BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;

    consolePane.setText("Output: ");
    while (true) {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }
        consolePane.append("\n" + line);
        logPane.append("\n" + line);

    }
```

Comment: If anyone wants to take a look at the code in which I get the output stream I can post that too!

Comment: Need more code including your handling of streams and threading.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have now added the code :) And I wrote and I quote "I have tried to get this right". And no, that does not mean that I would have a solution. I'm not a perfect logician but that's as far as my logic goes.

Comment: You don't appear to be using threads yet and I believe that this is required. And is this in a Swing GUI? If so, this makes threading even more important.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hmm.. One thread to start the cmd and the other to get the returned data? But aren't objects private within a single thread? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't understand that statement. A new thread exists only when one is created. Both `while (true)` and `r.readLine()`  are blocking, meaning that they will block flow of the code through the thread rendering the thread that contains them helpless.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I couldn't start a discussion chat... But what I meant was: Do you mean that I should start one thread to handle the commands and another thread to handle the output stream?

Comment: The commands that the user puts out could be done on the present thread, but the data coming in, and the `while (true)` loop (essentially the same block of code), need to be done in a background thread, yes. But if a Swing GUI (again you don't say), you must take care that all Swing calls are made on the Swing event thread.

Comment: You haven't replied to my comment, but I'm assuming that I'm correct, that this is a Swing application, and if so, please check out these similar questions: 1) [Java chat application using Swing (Conceptual)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247781) 2) [Blank Jframe load on chat TCP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531092) and [some more similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjava%5d%20%5bswing%5d%20chat%20threading).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry, I liked your comment to state that your comment really helped, I found help on Oracles website when it comes to background threading ty